# eliminating the n-highest values in a python list

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list as shown below:

```
List = [83, 36, 44, 66, 78, 34, 78, 55, 89, 100, 97]
```

What would be the easiest way to discard the two highest values in the list?

Is Pandas a route to go? Something like:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(
    List, 
    index =['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11'], 
    columns =['Names']
)
```

And something like:

```
df = df.nsmallest(len(List)-2, 'Names')
```

The thing that I find very tedious is manually defining the `index` in the pandas dataframe IE, manually typing in the `['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11']` could a for loop do this?

Thanks

Comment: you mean `df.drop(df['Names'].nlargest(2).index)` ?

Comment: What happens if the list is [1,10,10,10,11]. Do you want to drop just one 10 and one 11, or all 10s (since there's a tie) and 11. If the former, does it matter which 10 you drop?

Comment: You can do it in linear time (faster than sorting) if you store 2 variables

Comment: You do not need assign the index when you create the DataFrame

Comment: Do you want to order the values or not?

I've added all the possible solutions to my answer.

Comment: `largest = max(List)`, and `second_largest = max(filter(lambda x: x< largest, List))` would be faster than sorting. Then use `List.remove(largest)` and `List.remove(second_largest)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a possible solution in vanilla Python, given the simplicity of the problem I don't see a clear reason to use Pandas:

```
my_list = [83, 36, 44, 66, 78, 34, 78, 55, 89, 100, 97]
n = 2
print (sorted(my_list)[:len(my_list)-n])
```

Output

```
[34, 36, 44, 55, 66, 78, 78, 83, 89]
```

The technique used is called slicing and allows to easily cut a list according to our needs.

Here's a simple example to quickly grasp how this works:

```
a[start:stop]  # items start through stop-1
a[start:]      # items start through the rest of the array
a[:stop]       # items from the beginning through stop-1
a[:]           # a copy of the whole array
```

I've just read a comment from @EliasStrehle that had a good point about the potential need to preserve the original list as a whole (a full copy).

**In case we want to keep a copy of the original list:**

```
my_list = [83, 36, 44, 66, 78, 34, 78, 55, 89, 100, 97]
new_list = sorted(my_list)
n = 2
new_list = new_list[:len(new_list)-n]
print("Original list:")
print(my_list)
print("New list:")
print (new_list)
```

Output

```
Original list:
[83, 36, 44, 66, 78, 34, 78, 55, 89, 100, 97]
New list:
[34, 36, 44, 55, 66, 78, 78, 83, 89]
```

**In case we just want to keep the list order:**

```
my_list = [83, 36, 44, 66, 78, 34, 78, 55, 89, 100, 97]
n = 2
for times in range(n):
    my_list.remove(max(my_list))
print(my_list)


# Another way of writing the same thing in a more cryptic / minimalistic oneliner
l = [83, 36, 44, 66, 78, 34, 78, 55, 89, 100, 97]
[l.remove(max(l)) for _ in range(2)]
```

Output

```
[83, 36, 44, 66, 78, 34, 78, 55, 89]
```

Comment: This is a good solution if the list order does not need to be preserved.

Comment: Good point, @EliasStrehle.

I've added that too to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Pandas is indeed a simple way to solve this. You could use [`Series.rank`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.Series.rank.html):

```
l = [83, 36, 44, 66, 78, 34, 78, 55, 89, 100, 97]
s = pd.Series(l)

s[s.rank().le(len(l)-2)].values.tolist()
# [83, 36, 44, 66, 78, 34, 78, 55, 89]
```

Or using `nlargest` as @anky suggests:

```
s.drop(s.nlargest(2).index).values.tolist()
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Pitto, no need to slow yourself down by using Pandas.
This solution preserves the order of the original list.
It uses list comprehension in the last line. List comprehensions are fast (and fun)!

```
my_list = [83, 36, 44, 66, 78, 34, 78, 55, 89, 100, 97]
n = 2

my_list_sorted = sorted(my_list)
nth_highest = my_list_sorted[-n]  # Requires n <= len(my_list)

my_list_filtered = [x for x in my_list if x < nth_highest]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [heapq](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html), if the order of the output does not matters:

```
import heapq

lst = [83, 36, 44, 66, 78, 34, 78, 55, 89, 100, 97]
heapq._heapify_max(lst)  # convert to a heap O(n)
[heapq._heappop_max(lst) for _ in range(2)]  # pop the k max items O(k*log(n))

print(lst)
```

**Output**

```
[89, 83, 78, 66, 78, 34, 44, 55, 36]
```

The complexity of this solution is `O(n + k*log(n))`, sorting is more expensive `O(n*log(n))`.

Comment: Seems strange that the max variants are private.

Answer (score 1):

A numpy solution:

```
List = [83, 36, 44, 66, 78, 34, 78, 55, 89, 100, 97]
np.array(List)[np.argsort(List)[:-2]]
```

Output:

```
array([34, 36, 44, 55, 66, 78, 78, 83, 89])
```